# VBA Word - Documents.Open website URL but taken indirectly from a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a "self study booklet" from different website pages by getting their content in one single Word document.

I use **Documents.Open("URL LINK")** then add some presentation code to stack them together, which works fine. However, I sometimes get to up to 50 urls.

To avoid having 50 *sub pagenumberx ()* that are exactly the same except for one URL as well as have an overview of all the different URLs, I put them on a Word and want to change them directly on it, then have a macro read each link. I'm trying to use a FOR LOOP:

```
For j = 1 to 50
study = Documents.Open(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text)
Next j
```

However, this is what I get:
Error 5174
Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?
(https://the-url-that-i-put.com)

So obviously the code works since the link I put is correct in the error message but it seems that VBA only searches in my computer, and not online.

Anyone knows how to make it work please?

Regards,
Lucy

Answer (score 0):

Each paragraph ends with a carriage return (Ascii 13), which I assume should not be part of your url. Not sure if this will fix your error, but try this

```
For j = 1 to 50
set study = Documents.Open(Replace(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, Chr(13), ""))
Next j
```

Edit: Also you need to `Set` your `study` variable as it is a reference to a document. By the way you don't need to set the document to a variable unless you are going to do something within the loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that! Sadly, it still doesn't work :/ Also, yes I do a bit of stuff within the loop with study but thanks ^^

Comment: At which value of `j` does the error occur? Are you able to share an example url?